# Laravel Session Not Persistent

Tags: php, session, laravel

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for several days now. The Laravel framework randomly seems to loose the session.

Application Setup

php version 5.6.8

Laravel 5.1 / Anjular JS

Xampp Stack

So far I have tried these
 1. Changed the key in config/app.php as such

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'ThisNeedsToBe32CharactersLongDog'),
```

2. Generate a new application key using the following command

```
php artisan key:generate
```

3. use the php super global variable $_SESSION. This works great so the lamp stack is not likely the case.

4. changed the lamp stack just in case. Application build on Yii works fine on the same stack.
5. deleted the vendor folder and re downloaded all the packages using 
   composer install
6. change the session drivers, cookie, file, database. Didn't work either.
7. Browsed just about every stackoverflow questions regarding this and made the suggested changes.

Your help is greatly appreciated.Thank you

Addendum
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4576
This is an issue with Laravel 4.1. I am not sure if this is still an issue for Laravel 5.1 or not

Comment: How did you change the session drivers? That's the first place I'd look. (And if you're using DB persistence, what is your db config?)

Comment: `$_SESSION` and Laravel's `Session::` functions are **not** the same. Where are you hosted? Is it a multi-server setup?

Comment: @J.T Grimes, i changes the drivers on config/session.php file
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

Comment: @ceejayoz, i realized $_SESSION and Laravel's Session:: are not same, but somewhere it should be using the $_SESSION right? I could be wrong. Currently its on local machine and not hosted anywhere.

Comment: @elixir Laravel does not use `session_start` / `$_SESSION` at all. It uses its own class for session handling and stores its own files entirely separate form PHP's default functionality.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If you're using Laravel's file session driver, make sure that there is a storage/framework/sessions folder and that it's writable by the web process.

Comment: @J.T. Grimes I made sure that the web process was able to writer to the sessions folder. It has full access. When the user is randomly logged out, I also notice a new token being generated.

Comment: did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: we were using ajax. we didn't identify the root cause of the problem but it seemed making too many ajax calls(perhaps simultaneous calls) at the same time messed up the session